Drag and Drop from an external mounted drive to Brave/all apps doesn't work
I am having this very peculiar issue where I have a NAS at home, a Synology one to be more specific. I have this mounted on my Kubuntu system on a different drive, that I setup to auto-mount every time I boot the OS. I mount this from /dev/sdb2.
Thing is, for months now, I haven't been able to drag and drop files from that folder (/media/NewSSD/NAS) to, for example, WeTransfer to share files. I have to copy the files I want to share to the desktop (or any other folder within my main Kubuntu system), and then I can drag and drop that to WeTransfer.
For context, I use Brave as my main browser, but it's not browser limited since I use other software like Audacity, and when drag and dropping files from /media/NewSSD/NAS to Audacity it fails. It recognizes the file name, but no data gets transferred. The drive where the NAS resides, is mounted as root from what I can see in the Dolphin properties window.
I'm itching for a fix, as this would really improve my workflow, and doesn't make my desktop look like a mess.
